# Remove timestamp element from ws-security headers created by WCF

Tags: c#, soap, ws-security

I am consuming an old Java web service from WCF that requires the request in the form:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <wsse:Security mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss- wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="xxx" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-ssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        ...
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Using the following config hack "works" but I don't want the username and password exposed in config:

```
<binding name="bindingName">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
</binding>
...
<endpoint address="https://endpoint address"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bindingName"
      contract="contract"
      name="bindingName">

    <headers>
        <wsse:Security mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss- wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-8293453" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-ssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </headers>
</endpoint>
```

What I want to use is something along the lines of:

```
<binding name="bindingName">
    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
    </security>
</binding>
```

But this generates the `timestamp` element in the security element, which the java webservice borks on.

What I need to do is remove the timestamp from the XML it generates or have some sort of custom binding to do it for me.

I tried creating custom credentials, but this only changed the `usernameToken` element.

I have already looked at many, many SO questions (many from 2007 and earlier) including the following with no joy:

- [Remove Timestamp element from Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223156/remove-timestamp-element-from-security)
- [How to make WCF Client conform to specific WS-Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836653/how-to-make-wcf-client-conform-to-specific-ws-security)

What is the best, simplest and most elegant way to remove the timestamp element.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just found this from Scott Hansleman five years ago ... surely they have fixed it by now: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BreakingAllTheRulesWithWCF.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer on [Kristian Kristensen's blog post about his woes in integrating to a Java AXIS 1.X and WSS4J web service.](http://zianet.dk/blog/2010/12/20/getting-wcf-to-talk-to-a-java-axis-1-x-and-wss4j-web-service-part-3-of-3/). So much simpler and easier than the hacks I was trying previously.

You can solve this with a simple custom binding in App.config as so:

BUGFIX - there is a bug in previous version - forgot to add certificate in httpTransport

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBindingName">
                <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" includeTimestamp="false">
                    <secureConversationBootstrap />
                </security>
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
                <httpsTransport useDefaultWebProxy="false" requireClientCertificate="true" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
        <endpoint address="<endpoint address>" 
            binding="customBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="CustomBindingName"
            contract="<contract goes here>"
            name="EndpointName" />

    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This gives the correct SOAP ws-security header without the timestamp that confused the java server just by calling this code

```
var client = new [clientType]();

client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = [certificate];

client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = [UserName];
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = [Password];

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

// TODO wrap in try catch
client.Open();

var result = client.[action](new [RequestType] { ... });
```

Further Reading:

- Source of links to answer - [Kjell-Sverre Jerijærvi's blog](http://kjellsj.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/wcf-ws-security-ssl-transportwithmessag.html)
- Where I found the actual answer - [Kristian Kristensen's blog](http://zianet.dk/blog/2010/12/20/getting-wcf-to-talk-to-a-java-axis-1-x-and-wss4j-web-service-part-3-of-3/)